# Breaking axis to keep view readable in vega-lite

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I need to provide a bar plot of measures, some of them providing very high measures compared to the others.
In order to keep readable the bar plot, i attempted to use log scale, and to add a filter-outlier step before the plotting.

I then wanted to experiment an axis break, letting a large chunk of y values to be "hidden".

Since i didn't found any way to do axis breaks in vega, i tried to [use the repeat system](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/repeat.html#scatterplot-matrix-splom) to get two consecutive graphs, each showing the relevant portions of the Y axis using [scale domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134128/setting-a-maximum-axis-value-in-vega-lite):

```
{
    "data": {
        "values": [{"n": "A", "v": 1}, {"n": "B", "v": 3}, {"n": "C", "v": 170000000}, {"n": "D", "v": 11}]
    },
    "repeat": {
        "slice": [ [0, 20], [150000000, 200000000] ]
    },
    "mark": {"type": "bar", "clip": true},
    "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "n", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "v", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": {"repeat": "slice"}}}
    }
}
```

This yield a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is undefined`. I feel like i'm using too freely the repeat system.

- how can i make the repeat behave as expected ?
- is there any mean do or emulate axis breaks in vega ?
- what else can i do to keep my bar plot readable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple vertical concat and apply a transform filter for each concat:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"n": "A", "v": 1},
      {"n": "B", "v": 3},
      {"n": "C", "v": 170000000},
      {"n": "D", "v": 11}
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.v <= 50"}],
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "n", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {"field": "v", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.v > 50"}],
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "n", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {"field": "v", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting possibility. Thank you, i will try it soon.